# nested alignment with arbitrary align location

Tags: align, nesting

I would like for the alignment locations for one align environment not to interfere with the alignment of another environment.
For example, in the following code, I have long expressions for `g_1`, `g_2`, `g_3` that I would like to align with the `+` sign. I have to do this somewhat manually now, e.g.,

```
\begin{align}
  x &\coloneqq \argmin_x \big\{f(x) + g_1(x)\notag\\
    & \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\; + g_2(x)\notag\\
    & \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\; + g_3(x)\big\}\\
  y & \coloneqq f(x)
\end{align}
```

to get the desired result:
[image]

I would like something like the following syntax, but the issue is that the `&` inside the `aligned` throw things off.

```
\begin{align}
  x &\coloneqq \argmin_x 
  \begin{aligned}
    f(x) &+ g_1(x)\notag\\
    &+ g_2(x)\notag\\
    &+ g_3(x)\notag
  \end{aligned}\\
  y & \coloneqq f(x)
\end{align}
```

Comment: `\begin{aligned}[t]`. Remove all `\notag` commands that do nothing.

Comment: @egreg: Wow that is great, thanks. Should I delete this question or would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `aligned` is a good idea, but you need it `[t]`op aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:padmm_primal}
  x &\coloneqq \argmin_x \bigl\{f(x)
      \begin{aligned}[t]
       & + g_1(x)\\
       & + g_2(x)\\
       & + g_3(x)\bigr\}
       \end{aligned}
  \\
  \label{eq:padmm_primal-second}
  y & \coloneqq f(x)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Remove the `\notag` commands that do nothing useful. I added also a second label, but it's not mandatory. Also `\big\{` should be `\bigl\{` and similarly `\big\}` should be `\bigr\}`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}\label{eq:padmm_primal}
  x &\coloneqq \arg \min_x \big\{f(x) &&+ g_1(x)\\
    & &&+ g_2(x)\\
    & &&+ g_3(x)\big\}\\
  y & \coloneqq f(x)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]